# Why does a ViewModel lose attribute values after being assigned to a DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, xaml, mvvm

Recently I've discovered a strange behavior when I assign a ViewModel which comes back from a WCF service call to a DataContext in a UserControl element. When I first assign the ViewModel everything is fine. All XAML bindings are showing the correct and expected values if available.

But let's say I've saved changes in the ViewModel via another service call and get back an updated version of the ViewModel and now like to reassign the new ViewModel to the DataContext sometimes the DataContext and the ViewModel (which has been assigned) are losing attribute values (they are null *after* assigning).

Let me show you a simplified example to demonstrate

```
namespace MyProject.ViewModels
   {
        [DataContract]
        public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase //ViewModelBase implements INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            #region Properties
            private MyViewModelListItem _myViewModelListItem; //another nested ViewModel
            [DataMember]
            public MyViewModelListItem myViewModelListItem { get { return _myViewModelListItem; } set { _myViewModelListItem = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => myViewModelListItem); } }

            private string _aStringVariable; //just a simple string
            [DataMember]
            public string aStringVariable { get { return _aStringVariable; } set { _aStringVariable = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => aStringVariable); } }

            private MyEnum _myEnum; //an enumeration
            [DataMember]
            public MyEnum myEnum { get { return _myEnum; } set { _myEnum = value;RaisePropertyChanged(() => myEnum); } }
            #endregion
        }
    }
```

Here is an extract of a simplified code behind of an xaml UserControl

```
//some other code parts not related to the problem

// get the VM
MyViewModel vm = service.getMyViewModel();

if(vm != null){
    //assign the datacontext
    userControl.Grid.DataContext = vm; //everything is fine. all values are set as expected. Databinding works like a charm
}
```

Now let's imagine some changes in the vm via user input and data binding. The viewmodel is saved (calling a WCF service method) and after that I call the service again to get an updated version of the VM:

```
// get the VM again
vm = service.getMyViewModel();

if(vm != null){
    //assign the datacontext
    userControl.Grid.DataContext = vm;
}
```

When I set a breakpoint *before* the assignment of the new ViewModel all values of any attribute of the ViewModel are set (because the service filled them with values)

But then right after the assignment **some** of the attribute values are null. I cannot say which one. I'm using a lot of different ViewModels in my project and in this example maybe the string is not null and the nested ViewModel also. But the enumeration is suddenly null. And at another place in the project maybe something else is suddenly null.

I assume that the DataContext variable has a setter method which is doing something strange (or I get it totally wrong).

**Does anybody know what's happening here? And in addition what could be a "good" way of preventing this (maybe reassigning is the wrong approach).**

For now I just set the DataContext to null before reassigning the ViewModel but it seems not the best way, does it?

```
vm = service.getMyViewModel();

if(vm != null){
    //assign the datacontext
    userControl.Grid.DataContext = null;
    userControl.Grid.DataContext = vm;
}
```

**Edit**:

1. just to clarify: No viewmodels are saved into a database. They are properly converted to corresponding entities and then these are saved.
2. changed *this* to *userControl.Grid* to be more specific in the examples

Comment: I don't know, but could this be due to some two-way bindings?  That is: 1) viewmodel set to null, 2) view property updated via a binding, 3) another viewmodel property updated due to two-way binding.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your three points right. Maybe you could explain your thought a little bit more in detail?

Comment: @derroman Controls in the view may be modifying the data. Try removing all controls. If the problem disappears, try adding back until you find the one(s) causing issues.

Comment: Mh. But how could this be possible? Between getting the new ViewModel and reassigning it to the DataContext is one line of code...

Comment: @derroman Views are very complex. They subscribe to data changes and do a lot of magic under the hood.

Comment: See! And I want to know which magic is happening here... :)

Comment: Seems you should work more ViewModel-First and just create a new View for the new VM.

Comment: I am a bit confused about why you are getting a **viewmodel** back from a service, rather than a model, and why you are saving a **viewmodel** rather than a model. A viewmodel should be the datacontext for the view, and that viewmodel will have properties bound to UI elements on the view. One of those properties is very likely to be a model returned from a service, edited, and saved back. At no point does the VM need to change its context as it is just a property of the VM that is changing.

Comment: If I had to guess, based on what you have provided I would say it doesn't have anything to do with MVVM. I think it might have to do with your DataContract and DataMemebers. That usually means you're serializing stuff right? It's hard to tell because you didn't show it here but I would venture a guess that you didn't implement your DataContracts right on your 'MyViewModelListItem' objects